# How does the Docker assign MAC addresses to containers?

Tags: docker, containers

When I start new containers, Docker automatically assigns some MAC address to them. I am curious if there is a pattern to this assignment. Can the MAC address be changed?

$ docker network inspect bridge

```
"Containers": {
            "3386a527aa08b37ea9232cbcace2d2458d49f44bb05a6b775fba7ddd40d8f92c": {
                "EndpointID": "647c12443e91faf0fd508b6edfe59c30b642abb60dfab890b4bdccee38750bc1",
                "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:11:00:02",
                "IPv4Address": "172.17.0.2/16",
                "IPv6Address": ""
            },
            "94447ca479852d29aeddca75c28f7104df3c3196d7b6d83061879e339946805c": {
                "EndpointID": "b047d090f446ac49747d3c37d63e4307be745876db7f0ceef7b311cbba615f48",
                "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:11:00:03",
                "IPv4Address": "172.17.0.3/16",
                "IPv6Address": ""
            }
```

Answer (score 90, accepted):

Docker start assigning always the same mac `02:42:ac:11:00:02` for the first container and then is increasing by one each mac for each different container.

Not sure why they are using that mac address. It seems `02:42:ac` doesn't match any real vendor in oui databases. Look at the [official documentation](https://docs.docker.com/v1.7/articles/networking/) about this. They say:

> The MAC address is generated using the IP address allocated to the container to avoid ARP collisions, using a range from 02:42:ac:11:00:00 to 02:42:ac:11:ff:ff

Anyway, you can set any mac address on container generation using `--mac-address` parameter on the docker run command. For example doing a command like this `docker run -ti --mac-address 00:00:00:00:00:11 ubuntu:trusty`

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you very much! This is exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: "It seems 02:42:ac doesn't match any real vendor in oui databases".  Bit `0x02` in the fist octect of a MAC address indicates that it is "locally administered" so it will never be set in a vendor OUI. That guarantees that a docker-allocated MAC won't collide with a physical network interface's MAC address.  I can only guess what the `00x42` in the second octet is for (life the universe and everything?).  As @Norbert pointed out in his answer, the 3rd octect (`0xac`) is taken from the 1st octect of the IP address - 172.

Answer (score 2):

If you look at the MAC address of the container interface(s), you can see that the last 4 octets are the hex representation of the IPv4 address. This part is prefixed by `02:42:`
For example:-

The docker generated MAC address of the container interface with IPv4 address `172.19.0.6` would be `02:42:ac:13:00:06`

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out - I was trying to figure out exactly what the phrase "The MAC address is generated using the IP address allocated to the container" meant.

Answer (score 1):

The MAC addresses for Docker all begin with `02:42`. The remaining four octets represent the IP address of the container in hex. `0xAC` in hex is `172` in decimal, `0x11` is `17`, `0x00` is, well, `0`, and `0x02` is... `2`. Thus this MAC address represents a container with the IP address `172.17.0.2`. The default Docker `bridge` network is always given the IP range `172.17.0.0/16` by default, thus this would be the MAC address of the virtual Ethernet adapter given to the first container you run on a fresh Docker install.

See https://maclookup.app/faq/how-do-i-identify-the-mac-address-of-a-docker-container-interface for more information.