# Docker Licensing a product

Tags: docker, licensing

Apart from docker environment we used to look MAC address as unique key for licensing. For Docker MAC Address is changes on Reboot. What We can Look in docker for licensing ?

Answer (score 1):

Docker start assigning always the same mac `02:42:ac:11:00:02` for the first container and then is increasing by one each mac for each different container.

It seems `02:42:ac` doesn't match any real vendor in oui databases. Look at the [official documentation](https://docs.docker.com/v1.7/articles/networking/) about this. They say:

> The MAC address is generated using the IP address allocated to the container to avoid ARP collisions, using a range from 02:42:ac:11:00:00 to 02:42:ac:11:ff:ff

Anyway, you can set any mac address on container generation using --mac-address parameter on the docker run command. For example doing a command like this `docker run -ti --mac-address 00:00:00:00:00:11 ubuntu:trusty`. So you can control the mac of each container for licensing.

I copied my own answer on a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42946453/how-does-the-docker-assign-mac-addresses-to-containers/42947044).

Hope it helps.